# Complex htaccess rewrite for variable url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a shopping cart which has SEO links, i'm creating a option to refine the search option within the results displayed.

This is an example of what i am trying to achieve

Customer display a list of products
www.example.com/products/Drives-Bluray/view/list/category_id/30/sub_category/167

Then if customer want to search by manufacturer as well
www.example.com/products/Drives-Bluray/view/list/category_id/30/sub_category/167?manufacturer=LG

or if customer wants to order by manufacturer and price

www.example.com/products/Drives-Bluray/view/list/category_id/30/sub_category/167?manufacturer=LG&orderby=price

In my htaccess I currently have;

```
RewriteRule view/([a-z]+)/category_id/([0-9]+)/sub_category/([0-9]+)$ com_products.php?view=$1&category_id=$2&sub_category=$3 [L]
```

I've searched and can't seem to figure out how to have multiple variables, which may or may not be there using RewriteCond.

Can someone please give an example on the way forward with this?

Thanks

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to append a query to the end of your rewritten URL, you'll want to use the [`QSA` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa). This allows you to have that query string at the end of the pretty URL starting with `?` rather than `&`.